# Answer checking - a more elegant/efficient solution?

Tags: angular, typescript, coding-efficiency

I am writing an app for some students which auto generates questions (like speed = distance/time questions), does a little animation, and auto grades answers given by students. It looks like this:

[image: This is an example of the application in full swing]

**Details about my goal**
Whilst in general the code is not a problem and everything works just fine, I want to make one part more elegant and wondered if there was a Javascript solution to do so. Essentially what I want is to take some function that says '*is it this? is it this? is it this? ...*' into '*is it one of these, and if so which one is it?*'.

There are no expected or actual results as this works and I am trying to streamline. Similarly there are no errors.

Here is a stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrldtz?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

**HTML** example, with **Angular** syntax: This iterates over the questions that are needed to be displayed for the current question. This is the right hand side of the image above.

```
<form [formGroup]="formAnswers" (ngSubmit)="answersSubmitted()">
  <div class="question-container" *ngFor="let question of questionBank[0].questions; let i = index">
      <div class="question-question">{{ question.question }}</div>
      <div class="question-input">
          <input type="text" formControlName="{{ question.id }}" class="answer-input" maxlength="8">
      </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" style="float: right;">Submit Answers</button>
</form>
```

I have a stripped down example of the applicable **typescript** code below. The bit I want to streamline is in the 'answersSubmitted()' function. This is what is called from the HTML when an answer has been submitted. It will check the value entered against the value stored in the code.

```
formAnswers: FormGroup;
velocity: number = 0;
valueInitialSpeed = {'x': 0, 'y': 0};

// this is the database of questions. Only one is provided here as an example
questionBank = [
    {
        'questionText': `A tennis ball is hit from an overhand serve towards a net.`, 
        'startVelocityRange': 25.2,
        'angleAppliedRange': 12,
        'xAccelerationRange': 0,
        'yAccelerationRange': 0,
        'gravity': 9.81,
        'startHeightRange': [0, 0],
        'dataGiven': { 'velocity': true, 'yInitSpeed': false, 'xInitSpeed': false},
        'questions': [
            {
                'question':'What is the initial vertical velocity of the ball',
                'answerValue': 'yInitSpeed', // this helps identify the answer and refers to the dataGiven object above.
                'id':'getYVelocity' // this is the identification which gets put onto the input. It relates the answer given to the variable above.
            }
        ]
    }
];

answersSubmitted() {

    this.questionBank[0].questions.forEach(question => {

        // gets the value entered by the student from the relevant input box.
        var value = parseFloat(this.formAnswers.value[question.id]);

        // xInitSpeed refers to questionBank[0].question[questionid].answerValue
        // it identifies which value to check the input against in the questionBank array
        if(question.answerValue === 'xInitSpeed') {
          // this function checks whether the input answer and the calculated answer are roughly equal.
          // valueInitialSpeed.x is calculated when the question is generated.
          // this.tolerance is just a percentage of how tolerant we are being with answer values
          if(this.percentageWithinBounds(value, this.valueInitialSpeed.x, this.tolerance)) {
            // correctanswer is just what functions we run when the answer given is correct
            this.correctAnswer(question);
          }
          // this repetition is what I am interested in streamlining
        } else if(question.answerValue === 'yInitSpeed') {
          if(this.percentageWithinBounds(value, this.valueInitialSpeed.y, this.tolerance)) {
            this.correctAnswer(question);
          }
        } else {}// if{} ... etc etc
        
    });
}

private percentageWithinBounds(x, y, z) {
    // not applicable for now.
}

private correctAnswer(x) {
    // not applicable for now.
}
```

I feel like the questionBank array might need to be changed a little to accomodate this, and I am open to changes to streamline this. Whilst it is not a problem with this code, this is something I am going to reuse, and want to streamline both the coding process, and any more complex simulations made in the future.

Comment: Best to use Stackblitz for Angular code :)

Comment: Thanks, I will get right on that and replace my fiddle link :)

Comment: Added a stackblitz and removed the jsfiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrldtz?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so it looks like you're overcomplicating things for yourself by returning a variable which references an answer rather than simply returning the answer itself.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahlosh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I've simplified things hugely by just moving the answer into a property of the question.

If you need something more complex, you can turn `answer` into a function which calculates the appropriate value, something like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zckmwj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

You can put any logic you want in the answer function, you can even pass in the given answer and just return a true or false if appropriate.

I've left a couple of other comments there regarding minor issues. I highly recommend enabling `noImplicitAny` in your tsconfig.json - this will force you to type everything. If you don't do this, then what's the point of using Typescript? Types are there to help you!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense putting an answer reference in the database. I think my reluctance came from that in the future this will perhaps be database(d) and so I was trying to keep the database a base of data. But that is something I can sort later.

I didn't do the noImplicitAny thing because I had no idea it even existed or that types was the reason for typescript :-) Thanks, looking at it now.

Comment: No matter what, avoid any kind of answer-specific logic if you can. Think of ways to build a model which can apply to all of your answers, rather than handling each case separately. That's the way to reduce complexity and to keep things maintainable in the future.